# In Java we run classes, not programs - Meaning

Tags: java

I would like to ask you about sentence: "In Java we run classes, not programs". Is it correct?  I know the build process, but it seems to me that this sentence is ambiguous

Comment: I've never heart that sentence.

Comment: Where did you find that?

Comment: I don't think that's correct. Actually we don't have to instantiate a single class if we only do things in the main function and use only static methods there.

Comment: It was in my academic script but has not been widely explained.

Comment: I think it's a remark on Java's OOP architecture. By Programs, I imagine they mean that Java doesn't want you to do a top-down script. They want you to delegate your code to other classes and call that.

It's an attempt to be witty that has resulted in the whole sentence losing its value.

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer: You don't have to *instantiate* one, that doesn't mean you're not running it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Umm yeah.. This seem more like a philosophical problem to me and I only got 6 out of 10 from my philosophy test :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(As this is so wide-open, let's make the answer a community wiki...)*

I've never heard anyone say that (and would argue that it's so vague and slightly misleading you should ignore it).

Without context, it's hard to be *too* specific about what it's meant to mean, but it probably relates to the fact that many of the ways that Java programs are run involve a specific class that is the starting point.

For instance, if you're running a boring old program from the command line:

```
java DoSomething
```

...that's saying to run the `main` method in the `DoSomething` class.

Similarly, in an executable jar file, the manifest in the jar says which class to run the `main` from.

Similarly, a servlet is identified by a specific class implementing the appropriate interface and set up in the Java EE container's configuration.

But again, it's a really odd thing to say, not least because although the *entry point* may be a single class, of course that class then ends up using others to get its work done.

Comment: The sentence is obnoxious without a context. It is suitable after an explanation on why Java is one paradigm on Object Oriented Programming compared to other languages like C++, but alone means nothing.